# Unable to Add AAD nuget package manager in Xamarin Forms Application

Tags: .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms, azure-active-directory

I have a xamarin forms app for cross platform, and I'm trying to add the AAD authentication. But while installing the npm using the below command it is failing

```
Install-Package Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory
```

Below are the error message I'm getting relaated to nuget package version conflict.

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   NU1107  Version conflict detected for Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat. Install/reference Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat 27.0.2.1 directly to project MY_Portal.Android to resolve this issue. 
 My_Portal.Android -> Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter 27.0.2.1 -> Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.Palette 27.0.2.1 -> Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat (= 27.0.2.1) 
 My_Portal.Android -> My_Portal -> Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory 4.4.2 -> Xamarin.Android.Support.CustomTabs 27.0.2 -> Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat (= 27.0.2). My_Portal.Android   E:\Non GIT\My_Portal\My_Portal\My_Portal.Android\My_Portal.Android.csproj   1
```

I got some suggestions to install "Xamarin.Android.Support.CustomTabs" first, but none of them working, getting same error while installing it. I'm using Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: Is the answer resolved?

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

You should add `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectoryto` the DirectorySearcher project.

Use `PM> Install-Package Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory -ProjectName DirSearchClient-Universal`.

`DirSearchClient-Universal` here is your project name, for example, if your project name is `App1`, it should be :

`PM> Install-Package Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory -ProjectName App1`.

For more information, refer: [quickstart-v1-xamarin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v1-xamarin)